# How to revive HttpClient after network connection has been restored?

Tags: exception, xamarin, dotnet-httpclient

**How to revive `HttpClient` and make it see that the network is available again without fully restarting the application?**

In case when a Xamarin.Forms app was launched with no network connection available and then later network connection is enabled, `HttpClient.SendAsync(request)` throws `NameResolutionFailure` and it does not recover, no matter how many times the request is repeated.

It seems, HttpClient does not know how to recover when network connection appears.

To reproduce the issue in Android emulator:

- ensure your app is completely closed
- turn network off (set Data status to Roaming in emulator settings or use the status bar to toggle the data or LTE switch).
- launch your app, run a web request to verify that it does not work (obviously, you will need try/catch around the web request to avoid crashing)
- while the app is still open, enable the network
- run a web request - will get `NameResolutionFailure`
- only full application restart will revive HttpClient

The issue does not happen if I use domain names specified in etc/hosts file.

I tried to fully recreate `HttpClient` and resend a new request when the issue occurs, but that does not help. Only full restart of the app helps. 
Obviously, I cannot ask user to fully kill my app and start it again every time when user has turned on his network connection **after** launching my app.

Comment: Does it happen on emulator only or on real device too?

Comment: Yes, just reproduced on HTC One M8S with Android 6.0 API 23. Colleagues report, they have reproduced the issue also on a real iPhone. I found a few related posts on Xamarin forums which mentioned that there is a bug in Mono and it should have been fixed by now, but apparently it's not. It seems, some clever workaround might be required.

Comment: Are you using System.Http or Microsoft.Http nuget?

Comment: System.Net.Http.HttpClient, using in my PCL library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue. See:

Mono: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=45761

iOS: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=45763

Android:  https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=45383

The workaround is to manually set the DNS refresh:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.DnsRefreshTimeout = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work. I just hope that this timeout won't slow requests down, but for now I did not notice anything unusual.

Comment: If I understand correctly notes from bugzilla, this is fixed in Mono > 4.8.0